# Crear grilla de Botones utilizando TableLayoutPanel como contenedor

Tags: c#, .net

estoy intentando crear una grilla y se me ocurrió hacerlo dentro de un control TableLayout y estoy utilizando este codigo pero no se porque no me funciona me muestra un solo control o amontonados no uno en cada celda. ¿ que estoy haciendo mal.?

```
 private void InitTablero()
    {
        Button boton = new Button();

        for (int i = 0; i < 90; i++)
        {
            Tabla.Controls.Add(boton);
            boton.Height = 500;
            boton.Width = 500;
            boton.Font = BtSalir.Font;
            boton.ForeColor = BtSalir.ForeColor;
            boton.Text = (i).ToString();
            boton.Tag = i.ToString();
            boton.Enabled = false;               
            boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);            

        }

    }
    void Onb2Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        TxBola.Text = "Button" + e;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para ser que para que agregue mas controles al TableLayout, se deben instanciar para que no sean iguales por cada vuelta del ciclo, segundo como opcion si no queres no la usas, lo que te faltaba hacer era pasarle a que columna y fila querias agregar, ya que es una matriz ese componente, si no lo haces lo agrega automaticamente en fila y columna.
Tercero: Estabas seteando tu boton luego de haberlo agregado a la colleccion de Controls.

```
 private void InitTablero()
    {
        Button boton = new Button();

        int[,] matriz = new int[tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount, tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount];

        for (int f = 0; f < tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; c++)
            {
                boton = new Button();
                boton.Text = "Boton " + f;
                boton.BackColor = Color.White;
                boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);

                //TableLayoutPanelCellPosition position = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(f, c);
                //tableLayoutPanel1.SetCellPosition(boton, position);
                tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: huff! estaba remail. Soy nuevo en C# y ese codigo lo tenia en Vb.NET y funcionaba correctamente, Sólo lo adapte un poco y crei que deberia andar. Muchas gracias ya lo pruebo y te doy el Like

Comment: Gracias amigo me anduvo perfecto y ahora tengo 2 problemitas y uno es que no se como obtener el index del boton que se esta presionando y otro es si miras en la captura del link no puedo quitar esos bordes entre cada numero a pesar q no tiene pading ni relleno https://pasteboard.co/JchDzNR.png

Comment: Agregalo como otra pregunta para mantener el orden.

Comment: Y para que se usa la linea siguiente: `int[,] matriz = new int[tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount, tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount];`, me parece que está sobrando en este código.

Comment: Si podes sacarlo. Era para agregar los componentes y para pasarlo despues. me olvide de borrarlo

Answer (score 0):

Asi es como me quedo en al final gracias a la ayuda de @ramiro Barone

```
 private void InitTablero()
    {
        Button boton = new Button();
        int cont = 1;

        int[,] matriz = new int[Tabla.RowCount, Tabla.ColumnCount];

        for (int f = 0; f < Tabla.RowCount; f++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < Tabla.ColumnCount; c++)
            {
                boton = new Button();
                boton.Text = (cont).ToString();
                cont+=1;
                boton.BackColor = Color.White;
                boton.Click += new EventHandler(Onb2Click);
                boton.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                boton.Padding = Padding.Empty;                    
                Tabla.Controls.Add(boton, c, f);
            }
        }

    }
```